# How do I move the MySQL data directory?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to move the data directory of my MySQL database to a second disk array that I have as a mount point `/array2/`.

The problem I am having is I have tried everything and after I modify the location of datadir in my.cnf mysql will not start up again.

All I get is:

```
start: Job failed to start
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Forgot about app armour.

For anyone that is interested I did the following to move the folder.

Stop the mysql server:

```
stop mysql
```

Create the new directory:

```
mkdir /array2/mysql
```

Copy over ONLY the database folders:

```
cp -R /var/lib/mysql /array2/mysql
cp -R /var/lib/mysql/users /array2/mysql
```

Backup the `my.cnf` file:

```
cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf /root/my.cnf.backup
```

Edit the `my.cnf` file:

```
nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Change all mentions of the old datadir and socket to your new location

Mine became:

```
datadir=/array2/mysql
```

```
socket=/array2/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Update the directory permissions:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /array2/mysql
```

Rename the old directory:

```
mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql-old
```

Create a symlink, just in case:

```
ln -s /array2/mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Let AppArmor know about the new datadir:

```
echo "alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /your/new/datadir/," >> /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias
```

Reload the apparmor profiles

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor reload
```

Then start mysql:

```
start mysql
```

Comment: This is a good answer but you may need one more step to allow clients to connect to mysql. Add a new group with one line under it...
    [clients]
    socket=/array2/mysql/mysql.sock
where the socket= portion points to the new location of your mysql.sock file.

Comment: If you don't want to be bothered to merge `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` each time mysql receives an update, you can add `/array2/mysql/** rwk,` to `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld` instead. Mysql will still have access to the old data dir, but that probably isn't an issue.

Comment: `sed -i "s,datadir.*=.*,datadir=$new_dir,g" /etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Why only the database folders?

Comment: For anyone moving their datadir to ZFS (like I did), make sure you also add: `innodb_use_native_aio=0` in the `[mysqld]` section of your `my.cnf` file, since ZFS on linux does not support AIO. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_use_native_aio

Answer (score 23):

I found that AppArmor was the culprit by examining the `syslog`, and was able to successfully change the `mysql` data location by following this process.

*Please note that, in files edited below, lines starting with `+` were added, and lines starting with `-` were removed. You should not actually type/paste the `+` signs when adding lines to these files.*

I cloned the `mysql` directory to the new location:

```
sudo rsync -av /var/lib/mysql /new_dir
```

Then I edited the `datadir` line in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

```
-datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
+datadir     = /new_dir/mysql
```

Then I edited `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`:

```
sudo vi /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

```
-  /var/lib/mysql/ r,
-  /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
+  /new_dir/mysql/ r,
+  /new_dir/mysql/** rwk,
```

Then I restarted `mysql`.

Answer (score 13):

Be aware.

If you have InnoDB tables you MUST copy over the `ibdata*` and `ib_logfile*` files or you will not be able to use the the tables. You will get:

> 'Table 'databaseName.tableName' doesn't exist'

errors.

Run this copy command to copy over the `ibdata*` and `ib_logfile*` files.

```
sudo cp -p /var/lib/mysql/ib* /array2/mysql/
```

Comment: this should be a comment, it is not a complete answer

Answer (score 9):

I prefer to use mount with bind option so I avoid any further changes in Apparmor and Mysql configuration.

---

For example:

Suppose I want to move everything in `/var/www`.
Lets say this dir is my dev environment and it is mounted in a different partition

1. **First we need to stop mysql**:

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop mysql.service
   ```
2. **We move files** (preserving permission)

   ```
   sudo rsync -av /var/lib/mysql /var/www
   ```

   This will generate a directory `/var/www/mysql/` with all the content.
3. We remove everything in the old directory:

   ```
   sudo rm -r /var/lib/mysql/*
   ```
4. We mount the new directory with `bind` option in the old one.
   edit `/etc/fstab` and add this line:

   ```
   /var/www/mysql /var/lib/mysql  none  bind 0 0
   ```

   This will mount the `/var/www/mysql` in  our empty dir `/var/lib/mysql`
   The `bind` option here do the magic, it will populate `/var/lib/mysql` with the content of `/var/www/mysql` so for mysql and apparmor it will be the like nothing has changed.
5. Now we do the mount:

   ```
   sudo mount -a
   ```

   and restart mysql.

Comment: Can't thank you enough. Supposedly I have apparmor and selinux disabled, but changing datadir was not working. This approach fixed it. I have no idea why other approaches did not work, but it is solved. YOU MADE MY DAY!

Comment: This worked on my end. No more configuring apparmor on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You also need to move `mysql-files` directory, and add it as an additional bind mount. (Ubuntu 21.10)

Answer (score 7):

I just tried another way, that some may find useful:

copy with permissions intact:

```
rsync -avzh /var/lib/mysql /path/to/new/place
```

back up (in case something goes wrong):

```
mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/_mysql
```

create a new empty directory in place of old:

```
mkdir /var/lib/mysql
```

bind mount the new location to the old:

```
mount -B /path/to/new/place /var/lib/mysql
```

Hope that helps someone, because symlinking didn't work for me, and this was the simplest way

Answer (score 3):

If you move your datadir, you not only need to give the new datadir permissions, but you need to insure all parent directories have permission.

I moved my datadir to a hard drive, mounted in Ubuntu as:

```
/media/*user*/Data/
```

and my datadir was *Databases*.

I had to set permissions to 771 to each of the media, *user* and Data directories:

```
sudo chmod 771 *DIR*
```

If this does not work, another way you can get mysql to work is to change user in /etc/mysql/my.cnf to root; though there are no doubt some issues with doing that from a security perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You realize if you follow the commands verbatim from the accepted answer it will fail?

cp -R /var/lib/mysql /array2/mysql

Will copy /var/lib/mysql to /array2/mysql/mysql.

When you set your configuration file you better be putting in /array2/mysql/mysql as the directory or else your mysqld will fail to start.

The better copy commands would be:

cp -R /var/lib/mysql /array2/
cp -R /var/lib/mysql/users /array2/mysql

Just my 2 cents worth.