# 16.04, can't mysqld --initialize in non-default location

Tags: mysql

I was running mysqld on 14.04 with a non-standard --datadir (/usr/local/mysqld-test) & port (33306).  After upgrading to 16.04, I was no longer able to start up my test mysqld, so, following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server) and in the bug it links to [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1573279), I wound up going as far as:

```
sudo apt purge mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-common mysql-client mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common dbconfig-mysql
sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server
```

(In the process, it uninstalled amarok!?  *snarl)*

That still wasn't working, so I wound up nuking my entire `/usr/local/mysqld-test` (intentionally; in theory I have scripts to rebuild it).  The `mysql_install_db` command I had used before is deprecated now, and doesn't seem to understand the `-P 33306` argument, so instead I'm trying to use `mysqld --initialize-insecure`.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
mysqld --initialize-insecure --basedir=/usr/local/mysqld-test --datadir=/usr/local/mysqld-test/data
```

It fails:

```
mysqld: Can't create directory '/usr/local/mysqld-test/data/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2016-11-02T10:21:37.547443Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-11-02T10:21:37.549183Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Huh.  I thought I made that world-writable:

```
$ ls -al /usr/local/mysqld-test
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  2 kuhrusty kuhrusty 4096 Nov  2 03:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root     root     4096 Nov  2 03:13 ..
```

WTF?  Let's try that with `strace`:

```
execve("/usr/sbin/mysqld", ["mysqld", "--initialize-insecure", "--basedir=/usr/local/mysqld-test", "--datadir=/usr/local/mysqld-test"...], [/* 69 vars */]) = 0
...
```

It mmaps a bunch of shared libraries, sets some signal handlers, and then looks for config files (which I don't think I've messed with--I start it up manually, passing `--datadir`, `-P`, etc.):

```
stat("/etc/my.cnf", 0x7ffe13e99af0)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=682, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", O_RDONLY)     = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=682, ...}) = 0
read(3, "#\n# The MySQL database server co"..., 4096) = 682
open("/etc/mysql/conf.d/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
brk(0x271d000)                          = 0x271d000
getdents(4, /* 4 entries */, 32768)     = 120
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=8, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=8, ...}) = 0
read(4, "[mysql]\n", 4096)              = 8
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=55, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=55, ...}) = 0
read(4, "[mysqldump]\nquick\nquote-names\nma"..., 4096) = 55
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
brk(0x2713000)                          = 0x2713000
brk(0x270a000)                          = 0x270a000
open("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getdents(4, /* 4 entries */, 32768)     = 128
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3028, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3028, ...}) = 0
read(4, "#\n# The MySQL database server co"..., 4096) = 3028
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=21, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=21, ...}) = 0
read(4, "[mysqld_safe]\nsyslog\n", 4096) = 21
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/home/kuhrusty/.my.cnf", 0x7ffe13e99af0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/kuhrusty/.mylogin.cnf", 0x7ffe13e99af0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=1024, rlim_max=64*1024}) = 0
setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=5000, rlim_max=5000}) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=5000, rlim_max=5000}) = 0
umask(026)                              = 02
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2845, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2845, ...}) = 0
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2845
lseek(3, -1811, SEEK_CUR)               = 1034
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 1811
close(3)                                = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="tentacle", ...}) = 0
brk(0x2732000)                          = 0x2732000
brk(0x2724000)                          = 0x2724000
lstat("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/local", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/local/mysqld-test", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/local", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/local/mysqld-test", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/local/mysqld-test/data", 0x7ffe13e9d1d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\376\376\3\1\1\0\335\26\1\0008\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\0", 32) = 32
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\23\0\0\0\27\0\0\0D\0\0\0m\0\0\0\231\0\0\0"..., 4320) = 4320
read(3, "hashchk\0isamchk\0NO\0YES\0Can't cre"..., 71389) = 71389
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/usr/local/mysqld-test/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml", 0x7ffe13e9e2e0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
futex(0x1ddcf48, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
brk(0x2745000)                          = 0x2745000
open("/usr/local/mysqld-test/data/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mkdir("/usr/local/mysqld-test/data/", 0750) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

OK, now, I *think* that's where things go wrong (**note:** make sure you scroll to the bottom)... but *why?*  **Anyone** can create a file there!

```
write(2, "mysqld: ", 8)                 = 8
write(2, "Can't create directory '/usr/loc"..., 87) = 87
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
mysqld: Can't create directory '/usr/local/mysqld-test/data/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

WTF??  With this problem, the 14.04 -> 16.04 upgrade now ranks as about the third biggest mistake of my life... I feel like I've suffered one of those traumatic brain injuries where you forget how to read.  Those permissions are right, right??  Running `mysqld --initialize` under `sudo` doesn't make a difference.  Is there some incredibly stupid thing I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

ARGHH AppArmor is what hosed me.  The second answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137424/moving-mysql-datadir) is what gave me the hint I needed to look in the log:

```
[137519.814104] audit: type=1400 audit(1478218238.219:177): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mkdir" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/usr/local/mysqld-test/data/" pid=7126 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

Following [these instructions](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/AppArmor_Failures), I disabled AppArmor for MySQL:

```
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
cd /etc/apparmor.d/disable
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld .
```

And then confirmed that mysqld was no longer in enforce mode:

```
sudo aa-status
```

And then `mysqld --initialize-insecure` started & ran it the way I expected it to work two days ago.

(How/why did AppArmor get installed/enabled during the 14.04 -> 16.04 upgrade?  I don't think I'd heard of AppArmor before this; "your stuff is no longer going to work the way it used to" seems like the kind of information I should've been given during the upgrade!)

Comment: I see your problem. You're expecting Oracle MySQL to be a well-managed and sensible project. FYI, percona-server-server doesn't pull in AppArmor, and it doesn't have 5.7 perf regressions.