# How to move MySQL data directory

Tags: mount, mysql

I am trying to move the /var/lib/mysql data directory to a different drive. I have tried the solutions listed in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04 and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-change-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-using-a-symlink. In both cases I had similar issues to others where mysql could not be restarted.

I finally stumbled on to a solution in the comments to this thread: [How do I move the MySQL data directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137424/how-do-i-move-the-mysql-data-directory) by but in order to make it work I had to add another step. Currently what Im doing is:

1. `sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1p1 /mnt/test1` - here Im mounting the other hd (/dev/nvme1n1p1) on to a folder I created (`/mnt/test1`)
2. `sudo rsync -avzh /var/lib/mysql /mnt/test1` - per the commentary of the thread above I copied the mysql data directory to the mounted drive, so now the mysql data is on the external hd
3. I deleted `/var/lib/mysql` and created an empty directory (`sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql`)
4. `sudo mount -B /mnt/test1/mysql /var/lib/mysql` - here I mount the `/mnt/test1/mysql` directory back into `/var/lib/mysql`

I am sure this is the wrong way to do this, so any advice on the correct process would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: "I am sure this is the wrong way to do this" why do you believe that? :) It is not the safest method (I would have used a symlink) but it reads as a correct method

Comment: The symlink was one of the solutions provided on digitalocean but in both digitalocean solutions i got to the last step and was unable to restart mysql. 

I say this is the wrong solution because the absence of a cleaner solution makes me suspicious. Its also unclear why I cant mount the external hd directly to /var/lib/mysql but instead have to mount to a /mnt/test1 first.